# How to add more button in TabBarController?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I am developing a application.. 
A small Problem is That,We use here a TabBarController Application. and We Add Some NavigationControllers in as Tab Menus, We Done Successfully. One Requirement is That in Last tabBarButton we Have add a More Button. But It Not a View. Just a simple button. When We Press These Button They Perform Some action. I Tried but Its Not Done From My Side. Have u Give Me Some Guidance..
Thanks In Advance..

Comment: But How.. You Just Said, but Its First Problem. I have no idea to Do that..

Comment: accept the correct answer to your previously asked questions. just tick the mark against the answer that helped you.

Comment: i cant understand what you say.. please explain me briefly.. thanks..

Comment: You can click on your username to see a summary page for your account.  On that page, you can see your past **Questions**.  Go to those individual questions, and accept the answers that helped you.  To *accept* an answer, you click the checkmark ("V") next to the answer that solved your problem.  Also, you should [read this before going too much further](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/186251).

Answer (score 5):

When you add more than 5 `UIViewController` objects to your `UITabBarController`, iOS will automatically create the **More** button for you.

From [the Apple Documentation for UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> **The More Navigation Controller**
>
> The tab bar has limited space for displaying your custom items. If you
>   add six or more custom view controllers to a tab bar controller, the
>   tab bar controller displays only the first four items plus the
>   standard More item on the tab bar. Tapping the More item brings up a
>   standard interface for selecting the remaining items.
>
> The interface for the standard More item includes an Edit button that
>   allows the user to reconfigure the tab bar. By default, the user is
>   allowed to rearrange all items on the tab bar. If you do not want the
>   user to modify some items, though, you can remove the appropriate view
>   controllers from the array in the customizableViewControllers
>   property.

Comment: Yes your concept is good. but in our project requirement is that when we click the more button it show a new tab bar on top of tabBarController and it shows iems. so i try to do that. but it is not done. can you help me..

Comment: I'm sorry, @Piyush.  You've been asked more than once now to **accept** answers for the questions you've already asked, and you haven't done it.  You need to respect the way stack overflow.com works.